# How to restrict who can VIEW content of selected content types using Organic groups?

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

Using [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) 7x-2.7, how can I restrict which users are able to view certain content types?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to give it a try to use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, either as an alternative for [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) (as more and more people seem to be doing), or as an addition to it.

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For this specific question, you'd enable the `gnode` submodule, and for each group type you would define the appropriate permissions (view, edit, delete, etc) for the various Content Types. That's it.

For more details about how [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) compares to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og), refer to my answer to "[What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-group-module-versus-organic-group-module/197622#197622)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".